# array_udiff in symfony3 - can't find function

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, compare

I'm trying to use array_udiff

```
public function findFreeUsers($weekId)
{
    function compare_users(User $user1, User $user2)
    {
        return $user1->getId() <=> $user2->getId();
    }
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $week = $em->getRepository(Week::class)->findOneBy(["id" => $weekId]);
    $busyWeeks = $em->getRepository(Week::class)->findWeekBetweenDates($week);
    $busyUsers = array();
    foreach ($busyWeeks AS $busyWeek) {
        $tmp = $em->getRepository(UserWeek::class)->findBy(["week" => $busyWeek["id"]]);
        if ($tmp != null) {
            foreach($tmp AS $singleWeek) {
                $busyUsers[] = $singleWeek->getUser();
            }
        }
    }
    $allUsers = $em->getRepository(User::class)->findAll();
    $freeUsers = array_udiff($allUsers, $busyUsers, "compare_users");
    return $freeUsers;
}
```

Error

> Warning: array_udiff() expects parameter 3 to be a valid callback, function 'compare_users' not found or invalid function name

I declare compare_users() in public function in repository.
It's seems like symfony can't locate compare_users function. Same thing happend, when I declare coparision function after using array_udiff or declare it between public functions in repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you use callable function with closure, anonymous function or pointing the method of class. If you execute the method more than ones it'll try to redeclare the function and that function already exist. Moreover, the function could be declared elsewhere and it'll cause similar problem. That is why it's better to use the following solutions.

```
public function findFreeUsers($weekId)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $week = $em->getRepository(Week::class)->findOneBy(["id" => $weekId]);
    $busyWeeks = $em->getRepository(Week::class)->findWeekBetweenDates($week);
    $busyUsers = array();
    foreach ($busyWeeks AS $busyWeek) {
        $tmp = $em->getRepository(UserWeek::class)->findBy(["week" => $busyWeek["id"]]);
        if ($tmp != null) {
            foreach($tmp AS $singleWeek) {
                $busyUsers[] = $singleWeek->getUser();
            }
        }
    }
    $allUsers = $em->getRepository(User::class)->findAll();
    $freeUsers = array_udiff($allUsers, $busyUsers, function (User $user1, User $user2) {
        return $user1->getId() <=> $user2->getId();
    });

    return $freeUsers;
}
```

---

**Other options**

with closure:

```
public function findFreeUsers($weekId)
{
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $week = $em->getRepository(Week::class)->findOneBy(["id" => $weekId]);
        $busyWeeks = $em->getRepository(Week::class)->findWeekBetweenDates($week);
        $busyUsers = array();
        foreach ($busyWeeks AS $busyWeek) {
            $tmp = $em->getRepository(UserWeek::class)->findBy(["week" => $busyWeek["id"]]);
            if ($tmp != null) {
                foreach($tmp AS $singleWeek) {
                    $busyUsers[] = $singleWeek->getUser();
                }
            }
        }
        $compareClosure = function (User $user1, User $user2) {
            return $user1->getId() <=> $user2->getId();
        };
        $allUsers = $em->getRepository(User::class)->findAll();
        $freeUsers = array_udiff($allUsers, $busyUsers, $compareClosure);

        return $freeUsers;
}
```

With class callable

```
public function findFreeUsers($weekId)
{
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $week = $em->getRepository(Week::class)->findOneBy(["id" => $weekId]);
        $busyWeeks = $em->getRepository(Week::class)->findWeekBetweenDates($week);
        $busyUsers = array();
        foreach ($busyWeeks AS $busyWeek) {
            $tmp = $em->getRepository(UserWeek::class)->findBy(["week" => $busyWeek["id"]]);
            if ($tmp != null) {
                foreach($tmp AS $singleWeek) {
                    $busyUsers[] = $singleWeek->getUser();
                }
            }
        }
        $allUsers = $em->getRepository(User::class)->findAll();
        $freeUsers = array_udiff($allUsers, $busyUsers, [$this, 'compare_users']);

        return $freeUsers;
} 

public static function compare_users(User $user1, User $user2) 
{
    return $user1->getId() <=> $user2->getId();
}
```

Comment: Why can't I declare function inside a function?

Comment: technically you can but it's not the prettiest solution, is it?

Comment: it won't work because when you execute findFreeUsers more than once it will redeclare the function and it won't be possible because this function already exists

Comment: If function is __redeclared__ then error happens. Error like `Cannot redeclare function`.

Comment: sure it does and it also *proves* that the way OP did the code is *not* the *proper* way. I don't see whole code maybe there is some code that affects the function. If you put this code just to pure class with one method it'll work when executed only once.

Comment: Your answer describes how to do things in any other ways except the one OP chooses. Of course, it is an answer, but it doesn't explain why OP encounters error with `not found` function.

Comment: @u_mulder you seem to be quite "aggressive" here. Please, remember the spirt of SO and try to be polite next time. Thank you.